# Kotlin update textview every 1 second

Tags: kotlin, textview

i want to update text of progressbar and i have this error
i tried but not work anything
some advice?
why i cant update text ?

Thanks!

> 2021-10-26 22:31:00.555 6192-6227/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
> Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 6192
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8798)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1606)
> at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
> at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
> at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
> at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
> at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
> at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3593)
> at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3593)
> at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
> at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:9719)
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6311)
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6139)
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6091)
> at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$onResponse$2$1.run(MainActivity.kt:84)
> at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
> at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var textViewTur: TextView

companion object myCompanion {
    var test8: Int = 0

}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    textViewTur = findViewById(R.id.textTur)

    val url = "http://blynk-cloud.com/b3Uq-vB64Hz1D_X3AJ506Q9OwmQLwha7/get/V5"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    with(client) {
        newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("faillllllllllllllllllllllll")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                var test = body?.replace("[", "")?.replace("]", "")?.replace("\"", "")

                val tboiler = findViewById<CircularProgressBar>(R.id.PB_Tb)

                tboiler.apply {
                    val timer = Timer()


                    timer.schedule(
                        object : TimerTask() {
                            override fun run() {
                                progress = test?.toFloat()!!
                                myCompanion.test8 = progress.toInt()
                                textViewTur.text = progress.toString()
                            }


                        },
                        0,
                        2000

                    )


                }


            }


        })

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Timer class runs its code on a new thread, but you can only update UI elements like TextView from the main thread.

You can use `postDelayed` on a view to tell it to run code on the main thread after some delay, for example:

```
tBoiler.apply {
    postDelayed(2000L, {
        progress = test?.toFloat()!!
        myCompanion.test8 = progress.toInt()
        textViewTur.text = progress.toString()
    })
}
```

This will not run the code repeatedly. If you want to do that, you could move the delayed action into a separate function that can recursively call itself, and call the function to start the loop. You need to store the runnable in a property if you want to be able to stop the loop.

```
private val progressRunnable = Runnable {
    tBoiler.apply {
        progress = test?.toFloat()!!
        myCompanion.test8 = progress.toInt()
        textViewTur.text = progress.toString()
        loopProgress()
    }
}

private fun loopProgress() {
    tBoiler.postDelayed(2000L, progressRunnable)
}

private fun stopLoopProgress {
    tBoiler.removeCallbacks(progressRunnable)
}
```

Alternatively, your code could be simplified with a coroutine:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    textViewTur = findViewById(R.id.textTur)

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val url = "http://blynk-cloud.com/b3Uq-vB64Hz1D_X3AJ506Q9OwmQLwha7/get/V5"
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val response = try {
            client.newCall(request)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            println("faillllllllllllllllllllllll")
            return@launch
        }

        val test = response.body?.string()?.filter { it.isDigit() || it == '.' }
            .toFloatOrNull()
        if (test == null) {
            println("body cannot be parsed as Float: ${response.body}")
            return@launch
        }

        val tboiler = findViewById<CircularProgressBar>(R.id.PB_Tb)
        while (true) {
            delay(2000L)
            tboiler.apply {
                progress = test
                myCompanion.test8 = progress.toInt()
                textViewTur.text = progress.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}

// You can put this in a file for http utility functions
public suspend fun Call.await(): Response = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            cont.resume(response)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            cont.resumeWithException(e)
        }
    })

    cont.invokeOnCancellation {
        runCatching { cancel() }
    }
}
```